# 2-ended groups are virtually cyclic: reference

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, cyclic-groups, infinite-groups

It is often said (e.g., in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/327436)) that "It is standard that two-ended groups are virtually infinite cyclic". However, I cannot find a **simple** proof for this fact anywhere. Can anyone give me a reference?

Comment: While I do like the idea of simple proofs, and while in this case one might be able to find an "elementary" if somewhat intricate proof like the one in Meier's book, nonetheless I think that there is a very appropriate misquote for this situation: *If only you knew the power of Stallings' Ends Theorem!!* (apologies to Darth Vader).

Comment: One thing to keep in mind also is that, by applying Stallings Ends' Theorem, one obtains a better and more powerful conclusion in this situation: for every two-ended group $G$ there is a finite normal subgroup $N \lhd G$ such that $G/N$ is isomorphic to either the infinite cyclic group or the infinite dihedral group (this is a more powerful version of the statement quoted from Meier's book in the answer by @user1729). The statement you want is a quick corollary.

Answer (score 1):

Section 11.6 of Meirer's book *Groups, Graphs and Trees* gives a very friendly and self-contained proof of the following result (Theorem 11.33). The proof basically plays around with symmetric differences and cosets and intersections.

**Theorem.**
Suppose $G$ has $2$ ends.
Then there is a subgroup $H\leq G$ of index at most $2$ in $G$ and a surjection $H\twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ with finite kernel.

Corollary 11.34 of Meier's book then explains how to get from the above lemma to the result you wish.

The theorem is a reworking of the following slightly stronger result of Wall; see Lemma 4.1 in C. T. C. Wall, *Poincaré Complexes: I.* Annals of Mathematics, Vol. 86, No. 2, 1967, pp. 213-245 ([download](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/wallpoincare.pdf)). However, Wall's proof applies the fact that that $2$-ended groups are virtually-$\mathbb{Z}$ (thanks to the OP for pointing this out!).
Here, $\pi$ is a group and $\mathbb{Z}_2*\mathbb{Z}_2\cong D_{\infty}$:

**Theorem.** Suppose that $\pi$ has 2 ends. Then there is a finite normal subgroup $F$ of $\pi$, such that the quotient group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ or to $\mathbb{Z}_2*\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Lemma you referenced is Lemma 4.1 in Wall's paper, and its proof uses the fact that 2-ended groups are virtually cyclic. Wall references Epstein's Ends, Topology of 3-Manifolds and Related Topics, Prentice-Hall, 1962, pp. 110-117, but I couldn't find this paper :(. Neither could I find Meirer's book Groups, Graphs and Trees. Do you know where I can access one of them (Epstein's paper or Meirer's book)?

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor Thanks for pointing this out - I missread something in Meier's book, and then clearly didn't read the first line of Wall's proof at all! Unfortunately, I do not know where you can access either book from (Epstein's paper is actually a chapter in the book/proceedings "Topology of 3-Manifolds and Related Topics", and these can be tricky to find). However, Meier's book is an excellent, well-written introduction to geometric group theory, so if you are able to buy it then I thoroughly recommend it!

Comment: I found Epstein's paper on web archive! https://archive.org/details/topologyof3manif0000topo/page/114/mode/2up However, I will appreciate if you add some details about Meirer's proof to your post. It's a bit surprising that the proof of a "classic result" is so non-trivial to come by.

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor I'll edit a sketch-proof in if I get a chance. However, the proof is left as an exercise in, for example, Bridson and Haefliger's book *Metric spaces of non-positive curvature* and in Clara Löh's *Geometric Group Theory: An Introduction*. Stallings' Theorem goes so much deeper than this result, so they focus on the hard bits and set this as a decent introductory exercise (with hints!). Meier is pitched at a lower level than these books, which is why the proof is more relevant there.